# Expand the treeview items initially in kendoui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using kendo ui treeview widget control. I am dynamically getting the parents and child. How can i expand all the parents and child. I have wrote code:

```
          var treeview = $('#tree').kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: parent,
            dataTextField: ["question", "answer", "parentvalue"]
           });

            treeview.expand('.k-item');
```

but it is not working. How can i do that.

Comment: What is `treeview`? It should be equals `$("#your-treeview-id").data("kendoTreeView")`...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie yes treeview = $("#treeviewid").data("kendoTreeView");

Comment: Then can you explain a little bit more? For example, what is the code which create your treeview and where you call this `expand` method, ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using remote dataSource you will have no luck expanding it in such way because the items are still not loaded and created.

Instead use the **[dataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#databound)** event of the TreeView and set the **[loadOnDemand](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#loadondemand%20booleandefault)** property to false (so all the items are loaded initially then try to expand the items (you might need to do it recursevely) .

Comment: But the databound event not working out. will you provide an jsfiddle example. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

The `.kendoTreeView()` function actually returns the jQuery elements that the treeview was applied to, not the widget itself.

Instead, you need to do:

```
$("#my-treeview").data("kendoTreeView").expand(".k-item");
```

Comment: Yep, I'm doing exactly this, and on the dataBound event, but expand() is not doing anything

Comment: @PandaWood can you recreate it in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I'll give it a go, incidentally, setting a timeout and waiting for about 1 second after the dataBound event works ie (in coffeescript) setTimeout (->
   treeView.expand '.k-item'
  ), 1500. So it's like I have to wait for "render" as well as data being bound

Comment: If that is the case, then the data probably hasn't finished being read before you try to expand the tree items. The read is an async operation.

Answer (score 1):

As is your code, you only get the element created but not the data associated with it. You rather have to use such code:

```
$('#tree').kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: parent,
    dataTextField: ["question", "answer", "parentvalue"]
});
var treeview = $("#your-treeview-id").data("kendoTreeView");
```

as indicated in my comments above (and not `var treeview = $("#tree").kendoTreeView(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

function ExpandTree()
    {

```
   treeview = $("#MyTreeview").data("kendoTreeView");

    if(treeview != undefined)
        {
            treeview.expand(".k-item");
        }
}

function CollapseTree()
{


   treeview = $("#MyTreeview").data("kendoTreeView");

    if(treeview != undefined)
        {
            treeview.collapse(".k-item");
             treeview.expand(".k-first"); //To expand only parent
        }
}
```